# How do I check the XML files for flows that access Browser session Ids pls?

Tags: package.xml

I am new to Dev.
So far, I have retrieved the files from workbench.
How do I check the XML files for flows that access Browser session Ids pls?
I have VSCODE but don't know what to do next.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is no doubt related to Release Update for Winter 24 `Disable Access to Browser Session IDs in Flows`

> Previously, when a flow screen included the $Api.Session_ID variable, the browser session ID of the user that ran the flow appeared on the screen. An end user could use the session ID to bypass security controls. This update prevents flows from accessing the $Api.Session_ID variable.

- So, simply download your metadata from your source of truth (either Version control or some org) into your IDE (e.g. VsCode). Be sure that the Flow metadata type is included.
- Then, using the global search feature of your IDE, search for `$Api.Session_ID`.
- If the search results come back with hits in files that end in `.flow`, you have found instances of flows that need addressing.